# Best way to reverse the mathematical operator

Tags: regex, perl

I have some string which contain

```
$str = a > b;
$str1 = c < d;
$str2 = e = f;
```

What is the best way to do if i want to reverse the operator for example > become < , > become < , = become !=. The only way i know is to doing matching and get the a and b and using join function to join a and b with opposite operator. Any better way to do it?

Comment: This sounds like an `XY Problem`. Please explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your example is valid Perl code, but doesn't do what you think it does. Please [edit] your question and show actual real life examples.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your strings are really like this:

```
$str = 'a > b';
$str1 = 'c < d';
$str2 = 'e = f';
```

For one-character operators you can use the [transliteration operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tr.html) `tr///`, which is cheaper than regular expressions.

```
$str =~ tr/<>+-/><-+/;
```

For turning `=` into `!=`, you will need to fall back to a [substitution](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/s.html) using `s///`.

You can use a lookup hash for each negation, and turn the lookup keys into a pattern that you can use for the lookup.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %op = (
    '<'  => '>',
    '>'  => '<',
    '='  => '!=',
    '!=' => '=',
);

my $pattern = sprintf '(%s)', join '|', map quotemeta, keys %op;

my @strings = ('a > b', 'a < b', 'e = f', 'g != h');
foreach my $str (@strings) {
    print $str;
    $str =~ s/$pattern/$op{$1}/e;
    print " --> $str\n";
}

__END__
a > b --> a < b
a < b --> a > b
e = f --> e != f
g != h --> g = h
```

The `quotemeta` makes sure there are no regular expression meta chars in the pattern. That's not important for the example chars I showed, but it might be in your full use case.

This might be a good time to read [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Comment: /g is possibly wanted on the substitution

Comment: @simbabque Thank this work for me. But if the string is something like $str = " a=b and c=d ". How can i change two sign together?

Comment: @tim use  the `/g` modifier as ysth suggested.